# Universal app launching in portrait mode even though it's restricted to landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, sprite-kit, screen-orientation

whenever running a simulation on an iPad, even though it's restricted to landscape mode in the general settings and in code, It launches in portrait then switches to landscape.  The problem is when it launches, all the game objects are drawn to the screen before the orientation changes, causing the objects to be drawn below the viewing area.  When simulating with the iPad in landscape mode to start, everything is fine.  How can I prevent this from happening?

my code in GameViewController.swift:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: I solved it.  You have to go into info.plist in the support files folder and remove all portrait items under Supported interface options(ipad) manually.  Or you can just move a landscape option to the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

For swift3.0

To restrict different orientations for different views You need to do following things :

In App delegate File :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is OtherViewController {

            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All;

        } else {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
        }

    }
```